# Laptop having connectivity problems everywhere

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, connection

My laptop (HP Envy dv6, running 64-bit Windows 8) loses connection entirely every half hour or so. Connection will be extremely weak for much of that time, then regain strength before suddenly disappearing. This is a problem not just at home, but also on campus and in cafes (where other people have no issues). I have attempted to update drivers (Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 802.11b/g/n WiFi adapter) but can't find one that is more recent than the one I have now.

Comment: sounds like an internal connection problem with the antennae or just a flaky wireless card (they are usually a piggyback board in laptops).

Comment: yeah, I would say just change your wlan module. It's not a big deal. All you need is a screwdriver and one hand. They also don't cost a lot